# Tabula-py - pages argument

Tags: python, csv, tabula

```
tabula.convert_into(filename_final, (filename_zero + '.csv'), 
                    output_format="csv", pages="all")
```

How would I go about converting just pages 2 through the end?  The "area" changes for the convert from page 1 through the rest of the pages.

I am using the Python wrapper tabula-py

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [README](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py#options), the pages argument can be:

> **pages** (str, int, list of int, optional)
>     - An optional values specifying pages to extract from.
>     - It allows str, int, list of int.
>
> Example: 1, '1-2,3', 'all' or [1,2]. Default is 1

So I guess you can try something like `'2-99999'`.

Answer (score 2):

## **Tabula-py - pages argument**

```
from tabula import convert_into
table_file = r"Table.pdf"
output_csv = r"Op.csv"
#area[] have predefined area for each page from page number 2
for i in range(2, str(len(table_file))):
   j = i-2
   convert_into(table_file, output_csv, output_format='csv', lattice=False, stream=True, area=area[j], pages=i)
```